# Compare strings in two different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I have to compare the username from 2 workbooks in Excel using VBA. How does one do this?

For example :

- In workbook 1 : column A contains 10 names
- In workbook 2 : column A contains 10 names

I need to have the cell of column B in each workbook be colored Green or Red based on the match.

Comment: When you say "match", do you mean if the username in Workbook 1 shows up anywhere in column A of Workbook 2?  Or is a "match" if the username in Workbook 1 is in the exact same cell in Workbook 2?

Comment: Is the match supposed to take into account Low and Upper cases or is that not important to you?

Comment: There are plenty of examples here or there ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961996/lookup-on-another-sheet-in-excel). Please have a look, state precisely your question and show us your data. We will more likely help if you have already tried something.

Comment: How about this for simplicity `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,'C:\[Book.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0)),TRUE,FALSE)`. Unfortunately you cannot reference an external workbook with conditional formatting so you can have True or False in column B and then conditional format that cell.

Answer (score 1):

I "think" that you mean something like this, but I know I always need to be prudent. 
The code below should work, but probably you will want to set the ranges more dynamically.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Compare_Names()

Dim oBook_1             As Excel.Workbook
Dim oBook_2             As Excel.Workbook
Dim oRange_1            As Range
Dim iRange_1_Rows       As Integer
Dim oRange_2            As Range
Dim iRange_2_Rows       As Integer

Dim vArray              As Variant
Dim vArray_Found        As Variant
Dim iCnt                As Integer
Dim iCnt_B              As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set oBook_1 = Workbooks.Open("U:/Names_1.xls")
    Set oRange_1 = oBook_1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5") 'Can be dynamically set when needed
    iRange_1_Rows = oRange_1.Rows.Count
    ReDim vArray(1 To iRange_1_Rows, 1 To 1)
    vArray = oRange_1
    Set oRange_1 = Nothing
oBook_1.Close
Set oBook_1 = Nothing

Set oBook_2 = Workbooks.Open("U:/Names_2.xls")
    Set oRange_2 = oBook_2.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")
    iRange_2_Rows = oRange_2.Rows.Count
    For iCnt = 1 To iRange_1_Rows
        For iCnt_B = 1 To iRange_2_Rows

            ReDim vArray_Found(1 To iRange_2_Rows, 1 To 1)

            If Trim(vArray(iCnt, 1)) = Trim(oRange_2(iCnt_B)) Then
                oRange_2(iCnt_B).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                vArray(iCnt_B, 1) = True
            End If
        Next iCnt_B
    Next iCnt

    For iCnt = 1 To iRange_2_Rows
        If vArray(iCnt, 1) <> True Then
            oRange_2(iCnt).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next iCnt

    Set oRange_2 = Nothing
oBook_2.Save
oBook_2.Close
Set oBook_2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you want a non-case sensitive comparison you can use:

```
if UCase(Trim(vArray(iCnt, 1))) = UCase(Trim(oRange_2(iCnt_B))) Then
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a bit of code for something that can perhaps be solved using a formula in a cell?  Don't get me wrong, it's a very good example, and I'm sure you were able to write it quickly, but I wonder if the formula would be more maintainable.  I don't have Excel on this machine, so I can't try out a formula, like I say, but I think something like given in the example above might work?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the needs. The code given can be customized by the OP depending on his requirements. If an Excel formula is sufficient then he or she is also free to use that. But as stated in the comments above, that is unclear at this point...